# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in my nodeJS app

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello there i am trying to make a signup route and my code is as follows but everytime i get this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Can anyone help me with this code and tell me where the problem is,

```
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const { Mongoose } = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/user");
const { json } = require("body-parser");

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  const errros = validationResult(req);
  const { fname, lname, email, password } = req.body;
  var user = new User(req.body);

  User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(err);
    }
    res.json({
      msg: "Email already Exist",
      user: user,
    });
  });

  user.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(err);
    }
    res.json({
      msg: "Signedup Successfully",
      user: user,
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two responses being sent to client at a time.

In your case you are checking whether the user exists, If yes the response will be sent to client upon success. Then proceeding with the save operation is where you get the error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

To overcome the above behaviour,

- first check whether user exists already
- if no error then check the length of the data from the first query.

  - if length equals zero then proceeding saving and send response to client
  - else throw message saying `"User already Exist"`

**Working Snippet:**

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
   const { email } = req.body;
   var user = new User(req.body);

   User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
         return res.json(err);
      } else {
         if (user.length > 0) {
            res.json({
               msg: "Email already Exist",
               user: user,
            });
         } else {
            user.save((err, user) => {
               if (err) {
                  return res.json(err);
               }
               res.json({
                  msg: "Signedup Successfully",
                  user: user,
               });
            });
         }
      }
   });
};
```

Comment: the problem with this code is if email alredt exists in db it does not show any error

Comment: instead of this what i did is i added a middleware before signup and works fine